# Unable to locate asset (the file does not exist)

Tags: tapestry

I am going to achieve like this ${context:layout/images/${itemProperty.signImage}.png}. But I got the following error

```
Could not convert 'context:layout/images/${itemProperty.signImage' into a component parameter binding: Unable to locate asset 'context:layout/images/${itemProperty.signImage' (the file does not exist). [at classpath:net/web/app/sample/pages/Test.tml, line 30].
```

Please any one say how can I achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use expressions inside context expression. But you can obtain asset through [AssetSource](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/AssetSource.html) service:

```java
@Inject
private AssetSource assetSource;

public Asset getSignImage() {
    final String path = "layout/images/" + itemProperty.getSignImage() + ".png";
    return assetSource.getContextAsset(path, null);
}
```